# How can I sign XML SAML Assertions in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

When I try to sign XML (SAML) I get this error in a Web Api ASP.NET Core (2.0.2):

> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in the XML
>   document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Instance validation
>   error: 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256' is not a
>   valid value for SignatureMethodAlgorithm.

The target is full framework - .Net 4.7.1.

If I retarget to .Net 4.6.2 and .Net 4.7 the code is working.

UPDATE:
Turns out that I used a 3rd party library that expected the default hash algorithm in SignedXml to be sha1. And this was changed to sha256 as part of .net 4.7.1. And this was in fact not a signing problem but a deserialization problem. I fixed this by setting context switch according to .net 4.7.1 documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/retargeting/4.7-4.7.1

Comment: Without any code this is not such a good SO question. Might be better asked at ms support.

Comment: As a suggestion, maybe you [have to add](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2015/11/14/using-sha256-with-the-signedxml-class/) it now.

Comment: Turns out that I used a 3rd party library that expected the default hash algorithm in SignedXml to be sha1. And this was changed to sha256 as part of .net 4.7.1. And this was in fact not a signing problem but a deserialization problem. I fixed this by setting context switch according to .net 4.7.1 documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/retargeting/4.7-4.7.1

Answer (score 3):

I think I had this problem in the past (just not in a core project) here is how I solved it:

Add the following classes to your project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Web;

namespace xxx.Infrastructure.Crypto
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     <para>
    ///         The RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription class provides a signature description implementation
    ///         for RSA-SHA256 signatures. It allows XML digital signatures to be produced using the
    ///         http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256 signature type.
    ///         RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription provides the same interface as other signature description
    ///         implementations shipped with the .NET Framework, such as
    ///         <see cref="RSAPKCS1SHA1SignatureDescription" />.
    ///     </para>
    ///     <para>
    ///         RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription is not generally intended for use on its own, instead it
    ///         should be consumed by higher level cryptography services such as the XML digital signature
    ///         stack. It can be registered in <see cref="CryptoConfig" /> so that these services can create
    ///         instances of this signature description and use RSA-SHA256 signatures.
    ///     </para>
    ///     <para>
    ///         Registration in CryptoConfig requires editing the machine.config file found in the .NET
    ///         Framework installation's configuration directory (such as
    ///         %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config or
    ///         %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Config) to include registration information on
    ///         the type. For example:
    ///     </para>
    ///     <example>
    ///         <![CDATA[
    ///             <configuration>
    ///               <mscorlib>
    ///                 <!-- ... -->
    ///                 <cryptographySettings>
    ///                   <cryptoNameMapping>
    ///                     <cryptoClasses>
    ///                       <cryptoClass RSASHA256SignatureDescription="Security.Cryptography.RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription, Security.Cryptography, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    ///                     </cryptoClasses>
    ///                     <nameEntry name="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" class="RSASHA256SignatureDescription" />
    ///                   </cryptoNameMapping>
    ///                 </cryptographySettings>
    ///               </mscorlib>
    ///             </configuration>
    ///         ]]>
    ///     </example>
    ///     <para>
    ///         After adding this registration entry, the assembly which contains the
    ///         RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription (in the example above Security.Cryptography.dll) needs to
    ///         be added to the GAC.
    ///    </para>
    ///    <para>
    ///         Note that on 64 bit machines, both the Framework and Framework64 machine.config files should
    ///         be updated, and if the signature description assembly is built bit-specific it needs to be
    ///         added to both the 32 and 64 bit GACs.
    ///     </para>
    ///     <para>
    ///         RSA-SHA256 signatures are first available on the .NET Framework 3.5 SP 1 and as such the
    ///         RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription requires .NET 3.5 SP 1 and Windows Server 2003 or greater
    ///         to work properly.
    ///     </para>
    ///     <para>
    ///         On Windows 2003, the default OID registrations are not setup for the SHA2 family of hash
    ///         algorithms, and this can cause the .NET Framework v3.5 SP 1 to be unable to create RSA-SHA2
    ///         signatures. To fix this problem, the <see cref="Oid2.RegisterSha2OidInformationForRsa" />
    ///         method can be called to create the necessary OID registrations.
    ///     </para>
    /// </summary>
    public class RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription : SignatureDescription
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Construct an RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription object. The default settings for this object
        ///     are:
        ///     <list type="bullet">
        ///         <item>Digest algorithm - <see cref="SHA256Managed" /></item>
        ///         <item>Key algorithm - <see cref="RSACryptoServiceProvider" /></item>
        ///         <item>Formatter algorithm - <see cref="RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter" /></item>
        ///         <item>Deformatter algorithm - <see cref="RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter" /></item>
        ///     </list>
        /// </summary>
        public RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription()
        {
            KeyAlgorithm = typeof(RSACryptoServiceProvider).FullName;
            DigestAlgorithm = typeof(SHA256Managed).FullName;   // Note - SHA256CryptoServiceProvider is not registered with CryptoConfig
            FormatterAlgorithm = typeof(RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter).FullName;
            DeformatterAlgorithm = typeof(RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter).FullName;
        }

        public override AsymmetricSignatureDeformatter CreateDeformatter(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
        {
            if (key == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

            RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter deformatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter(key);
            deformatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");
            return deformatter;
        }

        public override AsymmetricSignatureFormatter CreateFormatter(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
        {
            if (key == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

            RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter formatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(key);
            formatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");
            return formatter;
        }
    }
}
```

in your settings area (as early as possible) add the following:

```
CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(xxx.Infrastructure.Crypto.RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription),
            "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"
        );
```

Comment: Wasn't there once a class `System.Deployment.Internal.CodeSigning.RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription`? Has it disappeared or moved to a new namespace / package?

Comment: That *does* exist, but it seems that it doesn't exist in .NET Core but rather specifically in .NET Framework (4.5+).